# Difference between cosine similarity and cosine distance

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy, cosine-similarity

It looks like scipy.spatial.distance.cdist cosine similariy distance:

[link to cos distance 1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)

```
1 - u*v/(||u||||v||)
```

is different from 
sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity which is

[link to cos similarity 2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

```
 u*v/||u||||v||
```

Does anybody know reason for different definitions?

Comment: The link that you labeled "link to cos similarity 1" is *not* cosine similarity, and it is not called that in the link.  It is cosine distance.

Comment: Think of the trivial case: *distance(X, X)* should be 0, because the distance from *X* to *X* is 0.  *similarity(X, X)* should be the *maximum* of the function that measures similariy (1 in this case), because *X* and *X* are as similar as two things can be.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, thank you, I fixed the name.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Good question but yes, these are 2 different things but connected by the following equation:**

> `Cosine_distance = 1 - cosine_similarity`

---

**Why?**

Usually, people use the cosine similarity as a similarity metric between vectors. Now, the distance can be defined as 1-cos_similarity.

The intuition behind this is that if 2 vectors are perfectly the same then **similarity** is **1** (angle=0) and thus, **distance** is **0** (1-1=0).

Similarly you can define the cosine distance for the resulting similarity value range.

**Cosine similarity range:** −1 meaning exactly opposite, 1 meaning exactly the same, 0 indicating orthogonality.

---

**References**: [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) [wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CosineDistance.html)

[image: From scipy]

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Terminology a bit confusing. I feel like cosine distance should be called simply cosine. Cosine similarity distance should be called cosine distance.

Comment: I agree but this is how it is defined in the engineering/math community.

Comment: Yeah, does not make sense to change it now.

Comment: @user1700890 see the first bullet point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#General_metric), for something to be a *distance* it must satisfy *"d(x,y) = 0 if and only if x = y. i.e.is zero precisely from a point to itself"*. The cosine *distance* satisfies this, cosine *similarity* does not. Hence the terminology.

Comment: @Dan Thank you Dan. Your explanation makes sense. Interesting how `cosine_similarity` is under `sklearn.metrics` while not being a metric

Comment: Take a look at the second sentence in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure), while not strictly a mathematical metric, in stats similarities are colloquially referred to as metrics as they fill similar roles. sklearn's metrics are more like measurements (colloquially).